# Not able to install Wireless Adapter drivers

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, drivers, adapter

I have downloaded some wireless adapter drivers (http://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wirele...et=37&system=6) Because my adapter did not work and i tried to reinstall the drivers. 
But once i downloaded the drivers i've only got 2 .cat files 2 .sys files and 2 .inf files. 
When i right click the .inf files i get the opportunity to press install to install drivers
ofc.. But it says that this .inf file doesn't support this installationmethod.

So i would like to ask how i can install the drivers in another way since i am really in need
to get these drivers installed so i can get my adapter working again.

Thanks!

Comment: The link in question goes no where for me. Usually there is an installation program associated with the drivers that will install the inf as well as make the needed registry settings, etc. Do you have an installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Control Panel\System\Advanced System Settings\Hardware tab\Device Manager, right click on your adaptor, click update driver software, browse my computer for driver software, navigate to your .inf file and hit 'Next'. The driver should install from there.

Comment: I was told to uninstall from my device manager. From another site

Comment: If you hit the Action drop down tab, and scan for hardware changes, the device should re-appear. It'll also be re-detected on a restart. Once it's listed, install the driver as above.

Comment: That's good news :)